# jQuery post request failing

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement an authentication API on iOS using jQuery Mobile. I am sending a post request using the `jQuery.ajax()` but the code is failing.

The code is given below and I am using jQuery Mobile framework along with Phonegap for iOS.

Is there anything wrong with this code ?
Is it possible to which HTTP error code is being returned (for example 500, 404, etc)?

```
function authenticate() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://someurl.com/authenticateUser",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify("{\"jsonText\":  \"{ \"username\" : \"Test\", \"password\" : \"testing123\" } \"} "),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

When I test the code through the HTML -

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Authenticate Me" onclick="authenticate();" />
```

I get a alert view saying:

```
index.html
[object Object]
```

**EDIT**: After reading some comments, I am now using `console.log (result)` and this is the error message that I am seeing in the log

```
    {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"Cannot convert object of type \\u0027System.String\\u0027 to type \\u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\\u0027\",\"StackTrace\":\"   

at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   at 

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\\r\\n   

at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\"}","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Comment: Do not use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log`.

Comment: Use the inspector and view the network traffic, that will give you an idea of what is happening

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I see a more detailed error message which I have posted above

Answer (score 0):

Looking at return alert that you have given its hard to tell what is going on. But if you want to know what error code is being returned then you can try something like [this](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/). Also is the POST request that you are making relies in the same domain?